# Unable to post data to my database on godaddy

Tags: php, mysql

I'm very new to php and this is my first project on this. Here I'm having a simple html form that submit data to mySql database.

I've created a table in mySql with 3 columns, 1st `JobId` which is an auro incriment field and primary key. 2nd and 3rd are `Title`, `JobDescription` which are varchars. In my html I fill the data and submit and the data should be posted in the table that I've created.

Here is my HTML.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Post Job</title>
</head>

<body>
    <form action="jobSubmit.php" method="Post">
        <input type="text" name="jTitle" placeholder="Enter Title" required/>
        <textarea name="jDesc" placeholder="Enter Job Description" required></textarea>
        <button type="submit" value="Submit"></button>
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

and here is my php code.

```
<?php
$jTitle = $_POST['jTitle'];
$jDesc = $_POST['jDesc'];

if (!empty($jTitle) && !empty($jDesc))
{
    $host = "localhost";
    $dbUserName = "muUserId";
    $dbPassword = "myPwd";
    $dbname = "Jobs";
    try
    {
        $conn = new mysqli($host, $dbUserName, $dbPassword, $dbname);

    }
    catch(Exception $ex)
    {
        echo 'Error : ' . $ex->getMessage();
    }
    if (mysqli_connect_error())
    {
        die('Connect Error(' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ')' . mysqli_connect_error());
    }
    else
    {
        echo $jDesc . ' and ' . $jTitle;
        //$SELECT = "SELECT JobId from OpenPositions Where JobId=? LIMIT 1";
        $INSERT = "INSERT into OpenPositions (Title, JobDescription) values (?,?)";

        $stmt = $conn->prepare($INSERT);
        $stmt . bind_param("s,s", $jTitle, $jDesc);
        try
        {
            $stmt . execute();
            echo "New Record Inserted";
        }
        catch(Exception $ex)
        {
            echo 'Error : ' . $ex->getMessage();
        }
        $stmt->close();
        $conn->close();
    }
}
else
{
    echo "Enter both Title and Desription";
    die();
}
?>
```

When I run it, enter `Test title` and `Tse Desc` and hit submit, I get the below screen.

And another point I missed to update. I'm hosting this on godaddy.

Please let me know where I'm going wrong and how can I fix this.

Thanks

[image]

**Update 1**

here is my schema.

[image]

Comment: where is the source for the function `bind_param`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**#Correct code is :**

```
<?php
$jTitle = $_POST['jTitle'];
$jDesc = $_POST['jDesc'];

if (!empty($jTitle) && !empty($jDesc))
{
    $host = "localhost";
    $dbUserName = "root";
    $dbPassword = "";
    $dbname = "Jobs";
    try
    {
        $conn = new mysqli($host, $dbUserName, $dbPassword, $dbname);

    }
    catch(Exception $ex)
    {
        echo 'Error : ' . $ex->getMessage();
    }
    if (mysqli_connect_error())
    {
        die('Connect Error(' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ')' . mysqli_connect_error());
    }
    else
    {
        echo $jDesc . ' and ' . $jTitle;
        //$SELECT = "SELECT JobId from OpenPositions Where JobId=? LIMIT 1";
        $INSERT = "INSERT into OpenPositions (Title, JobDescription) values (?,?)";

        $stmt = $conn->prepare($INSERT);
        $stmt->bind_param("ss",$jTitle,$jDesc);
        try
        {
            $stmt->execute();
            echo "New Record Inserted";
        }
        catch(Exception $ex)
        {
            echo 'Error : ' . $ex->getMessage();
        }
        $stmt->close();
        $conn->close();
    }
}
else
{
    echo "Enter both Title and Desription";
    die();
}
?>
```

**#What wrong in your code :**

1. bind_param() is a method of your $stmt object so you need to use it like $stmt->bind_param() insteadof $stmt.bind_param() | also $stmt.execute() will be $stmt->execute()
2. bind_param() first parameter about input type should be like 'ss' insteadof 's,s'

Take a tour for clear knowledge of bind_param() https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

[image]

**Live Demo**

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi @Shailesh, Yes. this is bug-free. Thanks a lot for this. it is now working fine, but the data isn't getting inserted, when I hit submit I see a message as `New Record Inserted`, any idea where I might go wrong?

Comment: This code is working fine let me share you a screenshot

Comment: Updated my question with the schema. I'm using `tinytext` and `longtext,` does s help us here? or do we have any other type specification?

Comment: Not an issue with data types. Are you getting any error message ? if not then please turn on error reporting on your server?

Comment: Wow brother. Thanks a lot. This really helped me. It is working fine now. The main error I did was taking `s,s` instead of `ss`

Answer (score 0):

Check the PHP error log file. You can found error log file location in php.ini, error_log="/path/to/error/logs".

or

place the
`error_reporting(E_ALL);`
at the top of php code, don't forget to remove it after the error is solved. This will display error on you page instead of return error server 500.